# Consulta dinâmica (data atual) via Web Service REST no Power BI

Tags: web-service, powerbi, powerquery

Bom dia, a todos!

Em meu projeto estamos consumindo os dados da empresa via Web Service REST. Hoje não fazemos a consulta de forma dinâmica passando a "mão" os parâmetros de data inicial e data final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu objetivo é que a data final atualize de forma dinâmica. Já criei uma consulta que pega o data atual mas não consigo colocar no parâmetro sem que gere erro na consulta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a mensagem de erro que recebo quando coloco o valor da coluna no parâmetro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho quase a certeza que estou errando na sintaxe. Quem puder me ajudar agradeço bastante.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: O Power Query utiliza a linguagem "M", você não vai conseguir utilizar o DAX dentro dele. Se os parâmetros fossem fixos, você conseguiria fazer desta forma. https://www.fourmoo.com/2016/11/23/power-bi-using-parameters-for-flat-file-csv-excel-sources/